# Existence of a strong antichain

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, matroid-theory, independence-results

Call an antichain (set of pairwise incomparable elements) $A$ of a poset $P$ strong if for every $p,q \in P$ with $p \leq q$ there exists an $a\in A$ which is comparable with both $p$ and $q$.

Consider the subsets of $\omega$ partially ordered by $\subseteq$, factorize it mod finite and then delete the smallest and largest element. A strong antichain of the resulting poset $P$ can be constructed by a straightforward transfinite recursion under the assumption that the reaping number is continuum. My question is if the existence of a strong antichain of $P$ is provable in ZFC alone?

The question has a great importance with respect to the existence of certain kind of infinite matroids. As far as I know it came up first in Bowler & Geschke's ["Self-dual uniform matroids on infinite sets"](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2016-144-02/S0002-9939-2015-12667-6/) paper.

Comment: I don't quite get your definition of strong antichain: The way I understand your definition, it cannot exist in $\mathcal{P}(\omega) \, /\, \text{fin}$: Let $A \subset P$ be a strong antichain and pick an $a \in A$. Define $q$ to be a stronger condition such that $a \setminus q$ is infinite. Set $p:=\omega \setminus (a \setminus q)$. Then (if your notation is to force upwards) $p \leq q$, but there cannot exist $b \in A$ which is both comparable with $p$ and $q$.

Comment: If the poset has a largest (or smallest) element $a$, then $A:=\{a \}$ is a strong antichain since $a$ is comparable with everybody. (The deletion of the largest and smallest element is to exclude these trivial strong antichains.)

Comment: Sure, $a$ must be co-infinite in my comment. But I don't see why there should be a non-trivial strong antichain. My comment above seems to prove the opposite, right?

Comment: If I understood correctly in your first comment you consider a poset which has a largest and smallest element and claim that it has no strong antichain. In my reaction pointed out that it is wrong since in this case we always have.  The existence of a strong non-trivial antichain in your poset is consistent with ZFC, my question is if it is actually provable in ZFC or independent of it.

Comment: No, I never said that my poset (actually this is also your poset, which you consider in your question) has a largest or smallest  element (I just forgot to exclude them). Assume that $A \subset  \mathcal{P} (\omega)\,/\, \text{fin}$ is a non-trivial strong antichain. In particular there exists $a \in A$ such that $\omega \setminus a$ is infinite. Now let $b \subset a$ be infinite such that also $a \setminus b$ is infinite. Define $q:=b$ and $p:= b \cup (\omega \setminus a)$.

Comment: Then $q \subset p$, but there cannot exist an $a' \in A$ such that both $p$ and $q$ are comparable with $a'$.
So either I misunderstand your definition of strong antichain, or non-trivial antichains can NEVER exist in $\mathcal{P} (\omega)\,/\, \text{fin}$.

Comment: Why do you think that there is no $ a'\in A$ which is comparable with both $p$ and $q$? For example $q$ itself can be in $A$ and hence is suitable choice for $a'$.

Comment: I think I figured out what is the reason of the misunderstanding. An antichain of a poset is a set of pairwise incomparable elements in my question. In the context of forcing this term is used differently: set of pairwise incompatible elements. Since you wrote 'stronger condition' I guess you used the forcing related interpretation.